# Can I do a HTTP post to a IP address?

Tags: http, vpn

Our client allows a VPN connection.This is the information I've received from them

```
Connecting to OKMMIS will be accomplished by your firewall via TCP using a socket.
Here is a typical transmission which should help in coding the software.


1. The transmission should look roughly like the following:

POST_/OKMMISPOS_HTTP/5.1
Content-Length:_521

ISA*00*__________*00*__________*ZZ*500000330______*ZZ*731476619______*090303*1414*U*004
01*390412079*0*P*:~GS*HS*500000022*731476619*20090303*141419*390412079*X*004010X092A1~S
T*270*390402706~BHT*0022*13*390412079*20090303*141419~HL*1**20*1~NM1*PR*2*OKLAHOMA_HEAL
TH_CARE_AUTHORITY*****FI*731476619~HL*2*1*21*1~NM1*1P*2*XXXTEST_PROVIDER*****XX*1234567
893~HL*3*2*22*0~TRN*1*00000006227390402706*9XXXMSGUTL~NM1*IL*1*TEST*TEST****MI*TEST~DMG
*D8*19820304~DTP*472*D8*20090303~EQ*30~SE*13*390402706~GE*1*390412079~IEA*1*390412079~
```

This is a 270 eligibility request. 
This is a 271 response

```
HTTP/5.1_200_OK
Content-Length:_448

ISA*00*__________*00*__________*ZZ*731476619______*ZZ*500000022______*090303*1702*U*004
01*000000001*0*P*:~GS*HB*731476619*500000330*20090303*170202*1*X*004010X092A1~ST*271*39
0402706~BHT*0022*11*390412079*20090303*1702~HL*1**20*1~NM1*PR*2*OKLAHOMA_HEALTH_CARE_AU
THORITY*****FI*731476619~PER*IC*CUSTOMER_CALL_CENTER*TE*4055226205*TE*8005220114~HL*2*1
*21*0~NM1*1P*2*XXXTEST_PROVIDER*****XX*1234567893~AAA*N**51*C~SE*9*390402706~GE*1*1~IEA
*1*000000001~
```

So as per my understanding this is a HTTP Post and is pretty simple. 
But they would like to do this by first establishing a VPN tunnel. They've sent some source IP's and destination IP's, port numbers to start with.

Finally my question is, How do I establish a VPN tunnel+ HTPP post. This is confusing me. 
I've requested them for a URL to post to. Should this suffice? or Can I do a http post to a IP?

Any ideas are very much appreciated

Comment: A URL is simply a string of characters chosen to be human-readable.  Through the wonders and magic of DNS, that URL is converted to an IP address anyway.  So yes.  You can post to an IP address directly.  As for establishing your tunnel......no idea.

Comment: Ok. What should this mean Connection will be accomplished by your firewall via TCP using a socket. 2) How do I combine this and Http post and vpn.. confusing

Comment: Say I start with this   HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(???))... Should I be giving the IP, port there

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh that makes much more sense, now that you added a second comment.  While I don't know how the HTTP post/vpn thing works (I'm not actually clear what all is happening there), you can do `...(new Uri("198.252.206.16"))` or `...(new Uri("www.stackoverflow.com"))`.  They should both resolve to the same server.  Having said that, it looks like the port is automatically set according to what protocol you are using, and cannot be set manually - so that may not be the correct option

Comment: Ok So would this help. new uri("68.109.249.167",3500)).. So the IP and the port.This is the destination.

Comment: if that were allowed, yes, but according to the documentation, that is not a valid constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.100).aspx